# Can't connect to MySQL database after moving to local

Tags: php, mysql

I can't connect my website to the mySQL database installed on the same box. I've had a website running on a shared host and decided to move it local.

- Installed Ubuntu Server - check.
- Installed LAMP with it - check.
- Installed phpMyAdmin - check.
- Copied website over - check.
- Copied database over - check.

My previous shared hosting provided used mysql.example.com in order to connect to the database.   I assume my local install is not setup like that, so in the database connection in the PHP file, I'm using `$host="www.example.com:3306"`.   No luck.   I've also tried using localhost.   Also no luck.

How WOULD I connect to the local database? I know I'm missing something terribly simple here.

Comment: Have you tried running `phpinfo()` in your PHP page to make sure MySQL is connected with PHP?

Comment: @VladBondarenko I did, just to make sure it was working okay.  I can also access phpMyAdmin using www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin.   From there, I was able to import the SQL database.   So things seem good...  checked the .conf file, mySQL is running on 3306.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your code, since PMA is working. Try using another one, or better yet show us the full code.

Comment: Would migrate, but then you don't show how you're exactly connecting

Answer (score 0):

May be a silly comment but I wanted to make sure that you were still filling out the database name, user log in and password.  Didn't see any code.

Remember your username and password are going to change accordingly to how you setup the Ubuntu server.  So if you created a user and password there, they need to match your connection credentials.

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks...  I actually still have the same code.   I updated the hostname, username, and password all with what should be on the new server.

Comment: Ah okay.  Well the only other thing I can think of is file permission settings for you Ubuntu server but I am not that familiar with the OS so leaving that comment as more of a thought than specific direction.